# Uploaded file comes in as blob if not on localhost? asp.net mvc4 using IIS express

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have my site running on my local network which allows users to upload zip files. But when i started testing it on my local area network (not on the localhost) the files show up as blob? For example: On my localhost where IIS express is running i can upload example.zip and it shows up in the upload folder just fine as example.zip. Now if i try to upload it from another machine example.zip shows up as blob. Interestingly enough if i rename the file back to the example.zip giving the right extention the file is fully intact and i can read it. I thought it might be folder permissions so i gave the upload folder full control from everyone to test and it still doesn't work. Here is the code from my API controller that save the file coming in.

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    // Enable both Get and Post so that our jquery call can send data, and get a status
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
        // Get a reference to the file that our jQuery sent.  Even with multiple files, they will all be their own request and be the 0 index
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
        // do something with the file in this space
        if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/test/" + file.FileName)))
        {
            Stream input = file.InputStream;
            FileStream output = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/test/" + file.FileName), FileMode.Append);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            input.Close();
            output.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/test/" + file.FileName));
        }
        // end of file doing


        // Now we need to wire up a response so that the calling script understands what happened
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = new { name = file.FileName};

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;

        // For compatibility with IE's "done" event we need to return a result as well as setting the context.response
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

}
```

Any ideas why my files get saved as blob? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after another couple hours trying to figure this out it ended up being a bug in Firefox that does this. I can get the real file name by looking at the headers.

```
var filenameHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Content-Disposition");
```

I then used Regex to parse the filename out of it because it comes like this:"attachment; filename=\"YourFileHere\""

Here is the link that pointed me in the right direction: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-fileupload/RjfHLX2_EeM