# HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName returning blob for image files

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext, ng-file-upload

I am sending a file as part of the FormData from AngularJs to .NET Web API as follows:

AngularJS:

```
var cabinetFormData = new FormData();
cabinetFormData.append('file', file);
```

Sending the above `FormData` as a parameter in the service call to .Net WebAPI

.NET:

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var fileRequest = httpRequest.Files[0];
```

While receiving the request on the server side, the `fileRequest.FileName` is always showing up as "blob" for any image files. Rest of the content is showing up fine. Getting proper File names for other format's like .pdf and .xml. I have checked the input, and it's sending all the formData.

[image]

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as a comment, but I don't have the rep yet..

If you're using Firefox when you see this issue, these links might help you out:

[Uploaded file comes in as blob if not on localhost? asp.net mvc4 using IIS express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473543/uploaded-file-comes-in-as-blob-if-not-on-localhost-asp-net-mvc4-using-iis-expre)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-fileupload/RjfHLX2_EeM

:)